# can't access other roles when limiting the access based on tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to allow my role to access only roles with a specific tag. Therefore, I've created a policy:

```
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:ResourceTag/key": "value"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and for each of the relevant role I've added the tag with the properties of - key - value.

However, when I'm using the specific role I keep getting these errors: 
`AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call iam:GetRole`

Any idea?

Comment: not sure why, but using: 
"Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "iam:ResourceTag/key": "value"
                }
            }
solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I created a policy with this json, and attached it to a role, which i ran with a lambda. I was successfully able to get the arn of a IAM:Role that had the key value tag and access denied on one that did not. Perhaps you aren't attaching the policy correctly or perhaps you're trying to perform the action using a different role, try creating an instance profile and attach it to a ec2 and run the commands from there or via lambda. 
tldr; the json is fine problem is somewhere else.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "iam:ResourceTag/key": "value"
            }
        },
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
```

}

Here is the full CF stack I used. It's yaml and Obviously the principle should be changed depending on your needs.

```
 Resources:
  Role: 
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
            - edgelambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - !Ref Policy
  Policy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
      Properties:
          ManagedPolicyName: Get_Role_With_Tag__Policy
          Path: /
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                - iam:GetRole
                Condition:
                  StringLike:
                    iam:ResourceTag/key: "value"
                Resource: "*"
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. 
not sure what else can be wrong- I'm attaching the policy through the console and also adding the tag through the console. So this should be quite trivial.
I have the role I'm using through trusted entity. can this might cause an issue?

Comment: Could you provide more details in your question? Is it a human who's going to be running this or a service and is that service part of aws? Basically try to explain what it is you're doing because IAM is a big and finicky beast and it takes a lot of time to really get to grips with it. I know it seems like it should be simple but it's not.

Comment: nothing very sophisticated-  I've a role inside a vpc with a trusted entity. from the other entity I'm trying to use this role in order to update the stack (for example update the code of a lambda function).  Each lambda has execution role to which I've added the mentioned tag. For some reason, it doesn't work. 
If I've removing this condition it does work.

I hope this explains things a bit better.

Comment: if the call is coming from an ec2 the role needs to have ec2.amazonaws.com as a trusted entity. if you edit my answer where it says service principle, run it in cloud formation and attach the role to the instance you're trying to do this from it should work.

Comment: the call is coming as a request from the user. I've added the trusted entity to the account I'm doing the request from. In fact, when removing the condition it works. So it must be something with the condition/the tags I'm using.

Comment: thank you for your help. using ForAllValues in the json solved it.

Comment: I added that to my answer, you can accept it if you like.